# remove a column from multi-dimensional array on MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a (n x m x l) array on MATLAB, and I want to remove 'k' columns (on 2nd-dimension). Finally, it may be a (n x (m - k) x l) size.

There is a constraints which is 'n' is fixed. Because MATLAB does not support assign null to array with more than two specific indexes when using colon indexing, I have no idea how can I do this.

Here is my sample code.

```
channel = 32;
trial = 75;
time = 2000;
data = MyCustomData(...);
disp(data); % ans = [32 75 2000]

for ch = 1:channel
    rejected_trials = []
    for trial = 1:trial
        if(is_rejected_trial(data(ch, trial, :))
            rejected_trials(end + 1) = trial;
        end
    end
    data(ch, rejected_trials, :) = []; % This line makes error
end
```

How can I reject some trials on multi-dimensional array with specific indexes?

Comment: It seems you don’t want to remove columns, but you want to remove specific values from each row. Unless you can guarantee that you remove the same number of elements from each row, this cannot be done in place, you will need to create a cell array to hold your rows of dissimilar size. Alternatively, mark your discarded trials by filling in NaN values.

Comment: By the way, your loop `for ch = 1:channel` does the same thing each iteration. You probably meant to use `ch` rather than `channel` inside it.

Comment: I changed 'channel' to 'ch'. Thanks for correcting. Also, I agree with your comment, so I will try to use your solutions.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to delete the data as soon as you determine it's rejected, and cannot do it in bulk at the end? Might I suggest first determining which trials are rejected (without changing the array inside the loop) and only afterwards selecting the "non-rejected" data from the array? Something like `valid_data = data(:, setdiff(1:trial, rejected_trials), :);`. This should work, and as a side effect, have better performance (since you avoid re-allocating a smaller `data` array for every invalid trial).